# Não consigo executar jar usando comando exec no php

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-3, jar

quando tento executar o sistema nao retorna nada, nao sei o que pode estar errado, tentei executar outro jar e funcionou, porem o msm n recebe nenhum parametro. o jar buscador funciona na linha de comando do linux normalmente

```
public function consulta(){
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $query              = $this->uri->segment(3,0);

    exec("java -jar ../public_html/assets/apps/buscador.jar '$query'", $resposta);

    $html = "";
    $conta = 0;
    foreach ($resposta as $value) {
        if($conta < 10 && $conta > 1){
            $documento = split("\t", $value);
            $html .= "<h2><a href=".$documento[1].">".$documento[2]."</a></h2>";
            $html .= "<p>".$documento[3]."</p></br>";
        }
        $conta++;
    }
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'consulta' => $html, 'resposta' => $resposta)));
}
```

Comment: Qual erro apresentado? Ou só não dá retorno?

Answer (score 0):

Olá. Segue as minhas considerações, de caráter não absolutamente conclusivo.

1. A primeira averiguação a ser feita é executar manualmente o comando `java`. O problema pode ser o `jar` em si e não estar relacionado com o CodeIginiter/PHP. O usuário do Apache/PHP pode não ter o privilégio necesário para executar o comando.
2. A segunda, por se tratar de linha de comando, é colocar o parâmetro $query entre aspas. Espaços, barras, e outros caracteres especiais estragam a formatação do parâmetro. Depedendo de quais caracteres, isto é irretratável.
3. A terceira é sanitizar `$this->uri->segment(3,0)`, pois o usuário vai digitar uma URI bem marota e começar a rodar comandos no seu servidor, mesmo que isto estragasse o retorno. Problema sério de segurança!

Esta forma de consulta por `exec( )` me parece pouco profissional. O uso de `exec( )` disputa contra as políticas de segurança do servidor. A função pode ser assícrona. Ela existe para quando realmente se precisa consultar artefados da máquina ou do sistema operacional do servidor. Isto não parece ser o seu caso, você deve estar tentando integrar dois sistemas, e dados da máquina que hospeda o sistema seriam irrelevantes.

Em se tratatando de Web, sistemas diferentes deveriam conversar por Webservice, ou numa solução bem mais simples, no mínimo por `file_get_contents( )`.